# Does L2-SVM involve always using the squared hinge loss?

Tags: svm, hinge-loss

Im trying to understand the math behind the L1 and L2 SVM but Im kind of confused at this point : in the following picture we see that the regularization term is squared for the L2-SVM. Does that mean that the loss will be squared hinge instaad of the standard hinge ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.